# Jenkins: no tool named M3 found

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Setting up a Pipeline build in Jenkins (Jenkins 2.7.2), copying the sample script for a git-based build gives: "no tool named M3 found".  The relevant line in the Pipeline script is:

```
def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have Maven installation available to do builds. You can configure using `Global Tool Configuration` and give name as 'M3'

```
def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
```

It says M3 is installed and assigns the return value to the mvnHome

Comment: Yes that was it!  I had Maven 3.0 installed but had to rename it to "M3" for it to work.

Answer (score 8):

make sure that the maven installation is configured in `hudson.tasks.Maven.xml` as below with name you want (I have `MAVEN3` below),

```
cat /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.tasks.Maven.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson.tasks.Maven_-DescriptorImpl>
  <installations>
    <hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstallation>
      <name>MAVEN3</name>
      <home>/usr/share/apache-maven/</home>
      <properties/>
    </hudson.tasks.Maven_-MavenInstallation>
  </installations>
</hudson.tasks.Maven_-DescriptorImpl>
```

**Followed by jenkins restart**

```
systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

It can be verified in UI as well,

[image: maven installation name]

Then, same variable can be used in pipeline script.

```
node {
   def mvnHome
   stage('Preparation') {
      git url: 'https://github.com/prayagupd/eccount-rest.git', branch: 'REST-API-load-balancing'
      mvnHome = tool 'MAVEN3'
   }
   stage('Build') {
      sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      archive 'target/*.jar'
   }
}
```